# How to fill in several dropdowns subsequently from JSON in Elm?

Tags: json, elm

We are stuck with filling in form from JSON data and need help. The component is about selecting the ward in the district of the given city.
The data structure  is a tree of Cities, Districts, and Wards with approximately following structure (everything is wrapped in GeoJSON):

```
// Cities: '/api/cities/berlin'
{
  features: [
    {
        type: "Feature",
      properties: { 
        slug: "berlin",
        name: "Berlin",
        districts: [
          {name: "Neukölln", slug: "neukolln", ...}
        ]
        },
      geometries: {...}
    } 
  ]
}

// Districts: '/api/cities/berlin/districts/neukolln'
{
  features: [
    {
        type: "Feature",
      properties: { 
        slug: "neukolln",
        name: "Neukölln",
        wards: [
          {name: "Britz", slug: "britz", ...}
        ]
        },
      geometries: {...}
    } 
  ]
}

// Wards: '/api/cities/berlin/districts/neukolln/wards'
{
  features: [
    {
        type: "Feature",
      properties: { 
        slug: "britz",
        name: "Britz",
        },
      geometries: {...}
    } 
  ]
}
```

In the view, three are  three dropdown boxes for selecting City, District and Ward, thus, when User select City, then District dropdown is filled from the `properties.districts` field of the JSON response.
Same is  applied  for the Districts dropdown: wards are filled in from the `properties.wards`
When the page is loaded it already has an injected JSON of all available Cities (and, accordingly their districts)

What strategy would you advise on:

1)  how to get currently selected city and hit server for next administrative divisions? I.e. when a user selects District, get its `slug`  and query server for the wards?

2) how to fill subsequent select from the response or injected JSON on the page? I.e. when user select another City, fill District select box with respective Districts?

Comment: The question feels a bit too broad. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to reduce the amount of `xhr` requests?

Comment: We are just trying to fill dropdown boxes with JSON data. The problem is that we don't understand how to fill both Parent and Child dropdowns from the same request/set of data (Cit and District,  District and Ward pairs).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I have done something similar in the past (in elm v0.17.0):

```
dropdown : List City -> Html Msg
dropdown cities =
    div []
        [ div []
              [ span [] [ text "dropdown label name" ]
              , selectOptions cities
              ]
        ]


selectOptions : List City -> Html Msg
selectOptions cities = 
      select [ on "change" ( Json.map (\city -> GetDistrictsMsg city) targetValue ) ]
            (List.map setOption cities)


setOption : City -> Html Msg
setOption city =
    option [ value city.name ]
           [ text city.name ]
```

And you will repeat the same for districts to get wards.

Answer (score 1):

### Start-up

If selected city is known, before the start-up, you can pass in as a flag to [Html.App.programWithFlags](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html-App#programWithFlags)

The same thing you can do to the list of cities.

Please see the [**http**](http://elm-lang.org/examples/http) example, it covers most of the stuff.

If you want to send `xhr` request on start-up, you might use a little neat trick for that:

```
init : String -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init topic =
  ( Model topic "waiting.gif"
  , getRandomGif topic
  )
```

Where `getRandomGif` will execute the `xhr` request on start-up, assuming that you have gotten some data for that from passing them as flags or from user input.

On every `FetchSucceed`, you should send the next `xhr` to grab the data for the next step.

### The flow

Please consider this flow chart, illustrating the flow of your multi step form. Dashed arrows point to steps, where you can restart the cycle, if you want to change the city/district at some point.

Caching layer is optional, Elm offers a variety of data structures for that.

[image: Multi-step form flow]